# Отправка GET/POST-запроса средствами чистого C++

Tags: c++, http

Как реализовать простой GET/POST запрос без использования сторонних библиотек?

Нашел много примеров, но там либо cpp-netlib, либо curl, а мне бы хотелось самому все это написать, но с сетью в С++ не работал, только через Qt. Было бы очень здорово увидеть маленький работающий пример :)

Comment: На чистом C++? Не смешите меня. Чистый C++ даже не имеет средств работы с консолью (`keypressed` и т. п.), потому что «а вдруг программа будет писаться под систему, на которой нету клавиатуры», так что уж на доступ к сети без библиотек не надейтесь. Пользуйтесь `boost::asio`, и будет вам счастье.

Comment: я знаю, что можно это реализовать через winsocket

Comment: winsocket — это не чистый C++, это WinAPI (системная библиотека Windows).

Comment: Если даже socket API не доступно, то в баше достаточно специальное имя файла использовать [/dev/tcp/$host/80](http://askubuntu.com/a/525550/3712)

Comment: @jfs: Но это POSIX-специфично, так что не пойдёт на Windows.

Comment: @VladD: как я уже явно упомянул это bash-специфично. Мне кажется, что просто  POSIX не поддерживает это. Я не вижу упоминания Windows.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Я решил проблему так:

```cpp
#include <cstring>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sstream>

char http[]={"http://"};
char host[]={"localhost"};
char parm[]={"/api/method.php"};


std::string getProtocol( std::string url )
{
    std::string protocol = "";

    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < url.size(); i++)
    {
        if( url[i] != '/' || url[i+1] != '/'  )
        {
            protocol += url[i];
        }
        else
        {
            protocol += "//";
            break;
        }
    }

    return protocol;
}

std::string getHost( std::string url )
{
    std::string host = "";

    url.replace(0, getProtocol(url).size(), "");

    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < url.size(); i++)
    {

        if( url[i] != '/' )
        {
            host += url[i];
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }

    }

    return host;
}

std::string getAction( std::string url )
{
    std::string parm = "";

    url.replace(0, getProtocol(url).size()+getHost(url).size(), "");

    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < url.size(); i++)
    {

        if( url[i] != '?' && url[i] != '#' )
        {
            parm += url[i];
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }

    }

    return parm;
}

std::string getParams( std::vector< std::pair< std::string, std::string> > requestData )
{
    std::string parm = "";

    std::vector< std::pair< std::string, std::string> >::iterator itr = requestData.begin();

    for( ; itr != requestData.end(); ++itr )
    {
        if( parm.size() < 1 )
        {
            parm += "";
        }
        else
        {
            parm += "&";
        }
        parm += itr->first + "=" + itr->second;
    }

    return parm;
}


std::string GET( std::string url, std::vector< std::pair< std::string, std::string> > requestData )
{
    std::string http = getProtocol(url);
    std::string host = getHost(url);
    std::string script = getAction(url);
    std::string parm = getParams( requestData );

    char buf[1024];

    std::string header = "";

    header += "GET ";
    header += http + host + script + "?" + parm;
    header += (std::string)" HTTP/1.1" + "\r\n";
    header += (std::string)"Host: " + http + host + "/" + "\r\n";
    header += (std::string)"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0" + "\r\n";
    //header += (std::string)"Accept: text/html" + "\r\n";
    header += (std::string)"Accept-Language: ru,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3" + "\r\n";
    header += (std::string)"Accept-Charset: windows-1251,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7" + "\r\n";
    header += (std::string)"Connection: keep-alive " + "\r\n";
    header += "\r\n";



    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    struct hostent* raw_host;
    raw_host = gethostbyname( host.c_str() );
    if (raw_host == NULL)
    {
        std::cout<<"ERROR, no such host";
        exit(0);
    }

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(80);

    bcopy( (char*)raw_host->h_addr, (char*)&addr.sin_addr, raw_host->h_length );

    if( connect( sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr) ) < 0)
    {
        std::cerr<<"connect error"<<std::endl;
        exit(2);
    }


    char * message = new char[ header.size() ];
    for(int i = 0; i < header.size(); i++)
    {
        message[i] = header[i];
    }

    send(sock, message, header.size(), 0);
    recv(sock, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);

    std::string answer = "";

    for(int j = 0; j < 1024; j++)
    {
            answer += buf[j];
    }

    return answer;

}
```

Comment: Кто же строки по значению передает, это же растрата! Инициализация строк кавычками - тоже ужас. Игнорирование итераторов - фактическая замена C++ на "C с потоками". И до кучи, приведение типов в стиле C.

Comment: Я вам советую использовать `boost.asio` как показано в примере Abyx

Comment: `std::string` - замедляет работу, из-за работы с кучей. Лучше было бы использовать `char*`, а ваше `header +=` заменить на `wsprintf` либо на `strcat`. Из концептуальных ошибок - 1. у вас константное число параметров header, а в реальности нужно переменное число, т.к. могут быть кукисы, авторизация, и много другого. 2. Не обработан ответ. Мусор в ответе. Но... думаю пример сгодится, как для начинающего.

Comment: Однако здесь используется масса сторонних библиотек.

Answer (score 10):

На "чистом C++" много чего нельзя сделать, потому что стандартная библиотека языка слишком миниатюрная, она не включает достаточно функционала, чтобы работать с HTTP.

В какой-то мере "полустандартной" библиотекой является *boost* (какие-то его библиотеки позже становятся частью стандартной библиотеки), поэтому можно воспользоваться *boost::asio*. Однако учтите, что это всё равно достаточно низкоуровневая библиотека. Простой HTTP-запрос вы сможете написать в пару строчек, но вы будете вручную разруливать все сотни современных возможностей HTTP: безопасное соединение, сжатие траффика, кэширование и так далее и тому подобное. Я уж молчу про новую версию стандарта. И если вы можете сказать серверу "я не поддерживаю сжатие, давай данные как есть", то проигнорировать HTTPS вы ну никак не сможете.

Вы изобретёте велосипед, который никому не будет нужен. Вы станете лучше понимать потроха HTTP, конечно, но кроме как для обучения смысла писать такой код нет.

Если вам нужны маленькие и работающие примеры, то посмотрите [Debunking Stroustrup's debunking of the myth “C++ is for large, complicated, programs only”](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/44278) — они там есть на всех языках, в том числе несколько на C++, а один из примеров написан самим Страуструпом.

Comment: [Пример (простого низкоуровневого) http клиента](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/iostreams/http_client.cpp) из `boost::asio`, [C++17 might provide similar API](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4370.html)

Comment: С сокетов уж точно не стоит начинать. Слишком низкоуровнево, это уровень TCP, а не HTTP. Сперва же лучше освоить HTTP (начать как минимум с WinInet - тоже часть WinAPI, но лучше с curl и прочего подобного, идеально - C# и .NET Framework [и снова я евангелист M$] а углубиться уже потом, с опытом), и освоить HTTP-сниффер хотя бы. Это и практичнее, чем голый TCP. Ну а "самый простейший" пример GET-запроса - это WinAPI-функция urldownloadtofile (скачиванием файла всегда есть GET-запрос)

Comment: Вот кто вообще такие ответы плюсует? Вопрос был, как самому сделать, для каких целей, вас не должно волновать. Скорее всего для обучения, и для этой цели как раз самому и надо написать код, кстати он не такой уж и сложный. А вы начинаете отговаривать человека, ну давайте тогда скажем что программировать вообще тяжко, и можно взять готовый сервер nginx например, ну или пойти работать блогером, а сложными вещами не забивать голову.Кстати сжатие и https добавляется довольно быстро, какой-нибудь крохотный wolfssl подключается запросто. Понятно что это будет проект только для себя.

Comment: @F10PPY Цели автора вопроса не имеют значения, этот вопрос в гугле будут находить все по запросу "запрос GET C++". Именно поэтому важно объяснение, почему, что и как делать *не* надо.

Comment: @Kyubey Не согласен. Человек ищет как ему сделать get на с++, приходит сюда, и вместо ответа, его просто отговаривают это делать. Лично я долго искал нормальные примеры реализации, в том числе, сервера на epoll, просто потому что почти никто это не делает. Может у человека дипломный проект или ещё что. Я считаю что нужно в первую очередь отвечать на вопросы, а советы давать уже в дополнение, вы вот дали ссылку, но там опять же с помощью библиотеки реализация. Ниже уже добавили код под линукс, вот пример под виндовс - https://stackoverflow.com/a/28369887/4739686 , не знаю почему это так сложно.

Comment: @F10PPY Человека не отговаривают сделать, человека отговаривают городить велосипед, потому что, приступая к его написанию, сложно оценить масштаб проблемы. Практическая часть ответа — "возьми любую нормальную библиотеку HTTP". Возможно, это надо как-то выделить жирным, а не подразумевать неявно. Последний параграф — самопиар и лулзы, что чести мне не делает, но преступлением не является.

Answer (score 8):

На данный момент в стандарте С++ нет средств для работы с сетью.

При помощи библиотеки Boost.Asio ([которую собираются включить в стандарт](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/p0112r1.html)) это можно сделать буквально тремя строчками кода:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0A00
#define BOOST_DATE_TIME_NO_LIB
#define BOOST_REGEX_NO_LIB

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream stream("httpbin.org", "http");
  stream << "GET /ip HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: httpbin.org\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";
  std::cout << stream.rdbuf();
}
```

С использованием Boost.Beast:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/core.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/http.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;

  boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query("httpbin.org", "http");

  boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_service);
  boost::asio::connect(socket, resolver.resolve(query));

  boost::beast::http::request<boost::beast::http::string_body> req(
      boost::beast::http::verb::get, "/headers", 11);
  req.set(boost::beast::http::field::host, "httpbin.org");
  req.set(boost::beast::http::field::user_agent, "MyAgent/1");
  req.set(boost::beast::http::field::connection, "Close");
  write(socket, req);

  boost::beast::flat_buffer buffer;
  boost::beast::http::response<boost::beast::http::string_body> reply;
  boost::beast::http::read(socket, buffer, reply);
  std::cout << reply.body();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Средствами чистого сиплюсплюса *можно* написать HTTP запрос, используя только iostream. А программу запускать, присоединив streams к netcat.

unix-way в чистом виде, если что.

Answer (score 4):

Можно на чистом с++ это сделать стандартными библиотеками `#include <sys/socket.h>` или  `# include <winsock2.h>.` Конечно не ручаюсь, насколько это работает сейчас, но раньше на сокетах как раз можно было написать вполне вменяемы TCP_IP запросы.
По первой либе [здесь](http://www.codenet.ru/progr/cpp/sockets-cpp.php) можно посмотреть пример

Comment: Упомянутые заголовочные файлы системозависимы и не являются стандартными. Их описания нет в стандартах C и C++.

Comment: И что с того, все названия функций стандартные, для линя можно заголовки передефайнить....