# Boost Asio read/read_untill некорректная работа

Tags: c++, boost, asio

Что то я окончательно запутался, без помощи не могу разобраться:
Пытаюсь прочитать ответ от сервера на get запрос, код простой:

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
tcp::resolver::query query(name_URL, "http"); //
tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
tcp::resolver::iterator end;

tcp::socket socket(io_service);
boost::asio::streambuf request;
std::ostream request_stream(&request);
request_stream << "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
<< "Host: " + name_URL + "\r\n"
<< "Accept: text/html\r\n"
<< "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";

    boost::asio::write(socket, request); //отправляем запрос
    boost::asio::streambuf response;
    boost::asio::read_until(socket, response, "\r\n\r\n"); // Читаем запрос

   // И записываем ответ в текстовый файлик
   std::istream response_stream(&response); // создаем объект потока
   std::string text; // сюда будет считывать из потока getline`ом

    string text_html=""; // Сюда записываем окончательный ответ

    while (!response_stream.eof())
    {
        getline(response_stream, text);
        text_html= text_html + text + "\r\n";
    }

    std::ofstream file("C:\\Response_html.txt");
    file<<text_html;
```

И теперь позвольте пожалуйста два вопроса:
1)Считывание данных от сервера происходит более, чем не полное, все заголовки приходят 200 ОК и прочая информация, но после заголовков буквально считывается несколько строк и все! Я не понимаю почему!
Решил посмотреть, точно ли read_until работает, как надо и заменил

-read_until(socket, response, "\r\n\r\n")
на
-read_until(socket, response, "200")

То есть я предполагал, что чтение будет ответа будет до 200 ОК, то есть в буффер ответа запишется только HTTP/1.1, но не тут то было, записались минимум все пришедшие заголовки, то есть read_until пропустил указанный для него критерий, читать до "200" и опять таки не понимаю почему :(

2)И позвольте второй вопрос, пытался использовать функцию read за меcто read_until, так теперь кидается исключение: Exeption:read:The end of file.
Но почему ?

Comment: Интересно, как это вы умудряетесь получить ответ, если никуда не подключаетесь?

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду, что я забыл написать: sock.open(ep4.protocol());
sock.connect(ep4); ?

Comment: Я их просто тут забыл скопировать, реально sock. open и connect присутствуют, тут все нормально.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых если Вы используете Boost.ASIO, то [используйте Boost.Beast](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/486374/177684) для HTTP.

Во-вторых если Вы используете HTTP, то вычитывайте `Content-Length` байт.

В третьих, [`while (!response_stream.eof())` это неправильно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/421083/177684).

---

Что касается самого вопроса, то Вы вызываете `read_until(socket, response, "\r\n\r\n");` и это заполняет буфер `response` заголовками + какой-то хвостик данных после "\r\n\r\n". Больше Вы из сокета не читаете, и поэтому в буфере больше ничего нету.

Так что вместо `read_until(socket, response, "\r\n\r\n");` читайте сразу до конца потока. И разумеется при это будет ошибка `eof`.

```
boost::system::error_code ec;
boost::asio::read(socket, response, boost::asio::transfer_all(), ec);
assert(ec == boost::asio::error::eof);
```

Comment: Abyx, Спасибо! Но я не понимаю почему read_until читает еще символы "хвостик" после \r\n\r\n ? Это разве не значит, что read_until читает лишнего не то что указано и значит работает некорректно ?

Comment: Abyx, а подскажите пожалуйста, а как функция read понимает, что весь ответ в буффер записан и что можно перейти к выполнению следующей строчке кода ? С read_until вроде как понятно, тут чтение до критерия, но у read же нет явного критеиия.

Comment: Abyx, до закрытие сокеты со стороны сервера ? А если будет параметр keep-alive ?