# Как реализовывается то, что не входит в стандартные библиотеки (С++)

Tags: c++, реализация

Значит, хотел узнать как реализовать GET/POST-запрос средствами чистого C++.
Нашёл [нужную мне тему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/478054/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-get-post-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-c?newreg=4ff4b0efc0ea4e399f82f6e5d866a896), где все в один голос говорят: "Так нельзя. Средствами стандартного С++ это не делается". Тогда я не очень понимаю как реализованы библиотеки, которые как раз таки добавляют эти возможности. Еще в школе говорили на информатике, что `#include` просто склеивает два файла (грубо говоря, копирует этот файл в наш).
Получается, что если взять содержимое файла, который мы **включаем**, и добавить в начало нашего кода - должно получится то же самое. Значит всё таки мы можем реализовать на "чистом С++", не включая "левые" библиотеки. Или моя логика неверна?

Comment: Использование системных вызовов операционной системы — это, по-вашему, "чистый C++" или "нечистый"? И, кстати, кроме заголовочных файлов используются еще и библиотечные...

Comment: Гуглите "системные вызовы".